# Git hub merge problem - deletes all old work

Tags: github, git-merge

The problem that i am facing is that when i merge my branch with the development branch to update my branch it deletes a big part of my work.

The strange thing is that when i try to solve it with Visual Studio to merge it doesn't not show any merge conflicts.

My branch is fairly up to date but the only diffrence is that the Entity frame work of our database is updated and the Entity frame work of your SQLite database is updated.

The are also placed in seprate projects should that should not effect my work.

The previous merge from dev did have some conflicts but all of them i had solved and my app work fine.

I got my work back with a Restoring a Revision in a New Local Branch but the problem still stay there that i have to merge my branch with dev to test the functions.

I couldn't find any solutions to the problem online.

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJZMe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rebase method that VonC suggest did not solve the problem.

But by creating a new branch with information of the older feature branch we could solve the problem by letting some other developer merge the dev branch to the new feature branch.

But i still don't know what the real cause is of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of merging dev to your branch, try instead to *rebase* your branch on top of dev (if you can afford to force push it, meaning if you are not several collaborator working on that same branch)

```
git checkout myBranch
git rebase dev
```

Comment: It did not solve the problem but i did learn something usefull, thank you